# Read a hbase table using spark

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, hbase, apache-spark

I have a table "Gazelle" with 216 columns, and i want to get some of their columns in a javaPairRDD. 
I've tried to follow this link :

[How to read from hbase using spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25040709/how-to-read-from-hbase-using-spark)
and this one : [how to fetch all of data from hbase table in spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534410/how-to-fetch-all-of-data-from-hbase-table-in-spark)

In order to import all jars i need i've added this dependency to my pom file :

```
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>fr.aid.cim</groupId>
<artifactId>spark-poc</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
        <version>0.96.0-hadoop2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
        <version>0.20.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


</project>'
```

and this is my code :

```
'SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("JavaWordCount");
    JavaSparkContext ctx = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
    //JavaSQLContext jsql = new JavaSQLContext(sc);
    //test hbase table
    HBaseConfiguration conf = new HBaseConfiguration();
    conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "192.168.10.32");
    conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort","2181");
    conf.set("hbase.master", "192.168.10.32" + ":60000");
    conf.set("hbase.cluster.distributed", "true");
    conf.set("hbase.rootdir", "hdfs://localhost:8020/hbase");

    //conf.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, "gazelle_hive4");
    String tableName = "gazelle_hbase4";
    HTable table = new HTable(conf,tableName);
    JavaPairRDD<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result> hBaseRDD = ctx
            .newAPIHadoopRDD(
                    conf,
                    TableInputFormat.class,,
                    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable.class,
                    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result.class);
    hBaseRDD.coalesce(1, true).saveAsTextFile(path + "hBaseRDD");'
```

But i have a problem with "TableInputFormat"

> Error : Cannot resolve symbol TableInputFormat. 
>   Is their another library i should import or another dependency i should add?

Note: I haven't created any XML file. 
Should i create the "hbase-default.xml" and "hbase-site.xml" ? If yes, how ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/HBase-and-non-existent-TableInputFormat-td14370.html) in Apache Spark user list, you might need a few more things.

If the error is happening at runtime, you should explicitly specify the hbase jars to Spark.

`spark-submit --driver-class-path $(hbase classpath) --jars /usr/lib/hbase/hbase-server.jar,/usr/lib/hbase/hbase-client.jar,/usr/lib/hbase/hbase-common.jar,/usr/lib/hbase/hbase-protocol.jar,/usr/lib/hbase/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar,/usr/lib/hbase/lib/htrace-core.jar --class YourClassName --master local App.jar`

If the error is happening at compile time, you might be missing a dependency. (hbase-server as stated in the thread.)

Comment: Yes thank you for your answer :) I missed the Hbase-Server. But now i have another error at runtime : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration.

Comment: Do you have any idea about the source of the problem ? Thank you

Comment: How is your job submitted to Spark ? Spark workers should have knowledge of all your external libraries. (Having dependencies in maven is *not* enough.)

Comment: here is how i submit the spark job : mvn clean install
/usr/local/spark/bin/spark-submit   --class fr.aid.cim.spark.JavaWordCount --master spark://adminuser-VirtualBox:7077  target/spark-poc-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

Comment: can you show me please how to give knowledge of all my external libraries to sparks workers ???

Comment: Note that i'm using two VM. The first VM contains the Sandbox of hortonworks with Hadoop, hbase, and zookeeper. And the second VM contains Ubuntu 14 with SPARK and java.

Comment: You should add the `--driver-class-path` and `--jars` parameters with the correct values as described in my answer.